# .htaccess redirect issue (from subdomain to directory)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Please help me with a redirect issue.

I am trying to redirect from `blog.project.org`  to  `http://www.project/blog`

I tried the following but it did not work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.project.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.project.org/blog [R=301,L]
```

also tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(blog\.)?project\.org 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule http://www.project.org/blog [R=301,NC,L]
```

none of these worked for me any suggestions?

Comment: Shouting (writing all caps) is not really welcome and tolerated on the web. Please don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.project.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.project.org/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think you made a typo there in your code. Shouldn't `RewriteBasae` be `RewriteBase` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.project/blog/$1 [R,L]
```